# Overlay high resolution image over low resolution image

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to load a low resolution image and a high resolution (same image), display the low resolution image and then when the high resolution image is loaded swap it out.

My first attempt was to just change the src when the onload function was called. This worked quite well on all browsers except firefox which showed a brief flash between swapping images.

Example (react code):

```
return <div>
    {this.state.hasLoaded ? 
        <img src={this.props.high}/> : 
        <img src={this.props.low}/>
    }
</div>
```

Then I tried creating two img tags. One with the low res and one with the high res. I place the high res image on top of the low res image and just let them both load. This seems to work but am I missing something. I feel I should be hiding the low res image with opacity, display or something but I'm not sure why I would need to.

```
return <div>
    <img className='image-high' src={this.props.high}/>
    <img className='image-low'  src={this.props.low}/>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to hide the low res image? Just let the high res one sit on top, no need to hide the low res image if you can't see it.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, exactly !

Comment: @MichaelCoker ok will do. Not sure why but I was positive that there is some reason not to do that :)

Comment: It's fine. but you can use opacity if you want to. Loads slower though...

Comment: @kjonsson the only concern I see with it is 1) performance of loading 2 images, but that doesn't sound like a concern for you and isn't the topic here, 2) accessibility like screen readers. Most people just see the webpage, so as long as the low res image is visually hidden (the other image is on top), that's all that matters. Hiding it with CSS would just further visibly hide it, but it's already hidden for 99% of your users. That last 1% tho might be using a screen reader (if they're blind or whatever) and that might read the "alt" text of 2 images instead of 1...

Comment: @kjonsson so in that case, you *might* want to use `display: none` on the low-res image, or even remove the low-res image from the DOM once the high res image has loaded. But that would also be for a (likely) small % of your users. Not sure if you care about that.

Comment: @MichaelCoker thanks mate that's some really good advice. Was looking for some reason why I might want to hide the other image. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: Progressive JPEG already doing that https://optimus.keycdn.com/support/progressive-jpeg/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a component that I use. It simulates the lowsrc="" property using two images overlayed over each-other.

```js
function LowSrcImg(
    props: React.DetailedHTMLProps<
        React.ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>,
        HTMLImageElement
    > & { lowsrc: string }
) {
    return (
        <div style={{ position: "relative", width: "100%" }}>
            <div style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, width: "100%" }}>
                <img {...props} src={props.lowsrc} width="100%" height="auto" />
            </div>
            <div style={{ position: "relative", top: 0, left: 0, width: "100%" }}>
                <img {...props} width="100%" height="auto" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```